# ember js query model for only certain params

Tags: ember.js

If I have an ember model say Person with attributes like name, age, height, address etc, and I want to fetch all records in the model but only want name attribute in returned JSON (name is the only param needed, so no need to return all params of the model), then is there a way in Ember to do that?  I searched for the query methods on Ember store but was not able to see any such example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
const listOfName = this.get('store').findAll('Person').mapBy('name')
```

For details refer
[mapBy](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/EmberArray/methods/mapBy?anchor=mapBy)

Comment: using this, you are still making a network call to fetch all the parameters, I do not want to do that as it will increase the load on the network call.

Comment: @BhavyaBansal This isn't really a concern of Ember. It is your API's responsibility to return the data in the form you want.  Maybe you want to create a custom endpoint to return only the names?